# Can't set data into list and then print it.

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to store data into a complex type list and then print it later. I am trying to use properties and then print it but it seems like I am missing something. Please help.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Color");
        string color = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter transmition");
        string transmition = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Name");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        List<DatabaseCar> arr = new List<DatabaseCar> { };
        DatabaseCar databaseCar = new DatabaseCar(color, transmition, name);
        arr.Add(databaseCar);
        foreach (DatabaseCar data in arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

abstract class Data
{
    protected string color;
    protected string engine;
    protected string name;

    public abstract void set(string color, string engine, string name);

    public string Color
    {
        get
        {
            return color;
        }
    }
    public string Engine
    {
        get
        {
            return engine;
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}

class DatabaseCar : Data
{
    public override void set(string color, string engine, string name)
    {
        this.color = color;
        this.engine = engine;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public DatabaseCar(string color, string engine, string name)
    {
        set(color, engine, name);
    }
}
```

The result I get from it is:

Enter Color:
Red
Enter transmition:
Manual
Enter Name:
John
ConsoleApp1.DatabaseCar

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx

Override this function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `Console.WriteLine` calls `ToString()` on an object that isn't specifically supported by one of its other overloads. `ToString()` by default returns the string representation of the Type.

To address this, you'll have to override ToString() with a custom implementation that does what you want.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    // construct the representation that you want and return it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the way you print your data.

```
foreach (DatabaseCar data in arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

`data` is an instance of the type `DatabaseCar`, which is a class defined by you. It contains many different properties of different types. So you need to tell C# how to print it.

There's two ways to go about it. One, a dedicated method to print an object of type `DatabaseCar`. You can customize how the print is done, this is a very basic example.

```
static void PrintDatabaseCar(DatabaseCar car)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name : {0}", car.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Color : {0}", car.Color);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Then you can call that method from your main like so:

```
foreach (DatabaseCar data in arr)
{
    PrintDatabaseCar(data);
}
```

Option two, you can override the `ToString()` method and provide functionality to print an object of type `DatabasCar`. This method has to go in your `DatabaseCar` class definition.

```
class DatabaseCar : Data
{
    public override void set(string color, string engine, string name)
    {
        this.color = color;
        this.engine = engine;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public DatabaseCar(string color, string engine, string name)
    {
        set(color, engine, name);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        result += string.Format("Name : {0}", name) + Environment.NewLine;
        result += string.Format("Color : {0}", color) + Environment.NewLine;
        result += Environment.NewLine;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
Thanks Everyone

```
 public override string ToString()
    {
        // construct the representation that you want and return it.

        return String.Format("Color {0},Engine {1}, Name {2}",color,engine,name);
    }
```